# Meteor adding okgrow:accounts-ui-react atmosphere package not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-react, meteor-1.4

I am running a `Meteor 1.4.2.3` application and everything has been running fine so far. I have been following the Level Up Tutorials and I've come to a point where I want to add user accounts.

In order to do that I'm using the `okgrow:accounts-ui-react' atmosphere package which can be found [here](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/accounts-ui-react).

I've followed all the steps by running the following 3 lines in the console:

```
> meteor add okgrow:accounts-ui-react
> npm install --save react-komposer classnames
> meteor add accounts-password
```

Those commands all ran successfully.

Now when I want to start my Meteor application by running `meteor` in the console I get the following error:

[image: Meteor Error]

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

Things I have tried that haven't solved it:

- Updating all my meteor packages using the `meteor update --all-packages` command
- Deleting the node_modules folder and running 'meteor' again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that React Komposer completely changed their api in the latest version for some reason. There is an outstanding issue regarding this here: 
https://github.com/okgrow/accounts-ui-react/issues/4

In the meantime, I'd suggest https://github.com/studiointeract/accounts-ui as development has continued on it again.

Comment: Thanks, thought I must have messed something up myself and neglected the fact that there may be a problem with the package.